# how to make an event that is always at the bottom in fullcallendar js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

how can i set the "cost my event" to stay below even though i reload the page.
i use fullcalendar on javasecript and i tried several ways like eventRender, eventDidMount, but still no result.
i use eventSource to call event data[image]

```
function renderCalender(val){

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  eventSources: [
    {
      events: [
        {
          title: 'My Event',
          start: '2022-05-31',
          end: '2022-05-31',
        },
        {
          title: 'My Event 1',
          start: '2022-05-31',
          end: '2022-06-02',
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      events: [
        {
          title: 'Cost My Event',
          start: '2022-05-31',
          end: '2022-05-31',
          url: 'http://google.com/'
        },
        {
          title: 'Cost My Event',
          start: '2022-06-01',
          end: '2022-06-02',
        }
      ],
      color: '#4caf50',
      textColor: '#fff',
    }
  ],
});
calendar.render();
```

}

Comment: You can't...fullCalendar just draws the events from the top down using the space available. If you want to radically change the rendering in this kind of way you'd need to fork the source code of this view and make a custom one, which of course is way more in-depth than just setting a few options via the API.

Comment: ok, how about it? Where is the reference that I can learn?, please help me

Comment: There's an intro in the documentation already: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js . Note that this is not a simple topic. Consider how much you really _need_ this feature, because it might take a lot of time to understand the code and then modify it to your needs.